# User spoils his answers

Tags: support, answers

I just noticed that a user Mudit Kapil is spoiling good answers. Just look at edit history.

https://askubuntu.com/a/576229/167850

and others. You can just search his last edits.

Not removing them, but just adding rubbish there.

I rolled them back.

Is there a way for moderators to stop it?

Comment: This seems bizarre - why would they do that? Seems like those edits were not intentional.  Also, that question has 4 upvotes, and some of his other answers have upvotes, yet they only have 1 rep?

Comment: 1 reputation is because the account is temporarily blocked.

Comment: The answer you were mentioning is an almost verbatim copy of the site the second (later) answer points to - without any reference.

Comment: Have you considered asking him (her, them, it) what happened?  The answer maybe "Sorry, I left my laptop logged in and my cat walked on the keyboard."  I only say this because my cat has walked on my keyboard, and hit what you would think was an awfully unlikely set of keys.

Comment: This happened yesterday, when did the other edits happen?  (That does look like cat typing, or kid typing)

Comment: All edits were at the same time within a half hour. You can't accidentally find all your answers and edit.

Comment: Perhaps they left their computer unattended, and someone went in and edited? Might be worth a moderator checking the IP they used at the time of the edits, and the IP they usually use.

Comment: @cybermonkey :) that is highly unlikely.

Comment: Has anyone asked @mudit-kapil what the story is? It's highly unlikely that someone would purposely destroy their own answers. I'd be more inclined to believe that there was some sort of security breach (stolen password, left system logged in, in an insecure location)

Comment: Mudit gone on another rampage? Last time I spent a good while rolling back his changes, following the feed, and flagged one post.